# I want to capture comments from java file using python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

For documentation purpose, I want to capture the comments of every function which lies above its code.

I am able to iterate the file to their function names. As soon as I get the function name line, I want to capture its comment which is above it.
comment are in '/** xxx */' block

```
/**
* this is the comment
* this is the comment
* this is the comment
*/
@Attribute(type = Attribute.STRING.class)
String RESPONSE_TEXT = "responseText";

/**
* this is the comment
* this is the comment
*/
@Attribute(type = Attribute.LONG.class)
String TIME = "clTimestamp";
```

Comment: Do every *function name line* starts with `@`?

Comment: @Daweo Yes! it starts with ```@attribute```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this need to work:

```
data = open(file_name).read()
data = data.split('/**')
old = data
data = list()
for i in old:
    data.extend(old.split('*/'))
comments = []
for i in range(1, len(data), 2):
    comments.append(data[i])
for k in comments:
    print(k)
```

Comment: `data = data.split('*/')` is likely to cause `'list' object has no attribute 'split'` because the second line changes the content of `data` from the bytes of the file in string to a list and lists don't have a member method called `split()`.

Comment: The same problem is going to occur on the 6th line because you've assigned `data` the return value of `data.split()` which is a `list`.

Comment: i have fixed that as well

Comment: I suggest you run your code before posting it as a solution. Your code still doesn't work. Check the 6th line. You're trying to run `split(...)` on `old`, which you've assigned `data`, which in turn was assigned the return value of `data.split(...)`. `data.split(...)` returns a `list`.

Answer (score 1):

Now when I know function name line starts with `@Attribute` it is quite easy to get it done using regular expression (`re` module), which can be done following way:

```
import re
content = '''
/**
* this is the comment
* this is the comment
* this is the comment
*/
@Attribute(type = Attribute.STRING.class)
String RESPONSE_TEXT = "responseText";

/**
* this is the comment
* this is the comment
*/
@Attribute(type = Attribute.LONG.class)
String TIME = "clTimestamp";
'''
comments = re.findall(r'(/\*\*.*?\*/)\n(@Attribute[^\n]*)',content,re.DOTALL)

print('Function comments:')
for i in comments:
    print(i[1])
    print(i[0])
    print('\n')
```

Output:

```
Function comments
@Attribute(type = Attribute.STRING.class)
/**
* this is the comment
* this is the comment
* this is the comment
*/


@Attribute(type = Attribute.LONG.class)
/**
* this is the comment
* this is the comment
*/
```

For clarity I hardcoded `content`, I used `re.findall` with pattern which have two groups, one is for comment, second for name, thus it give `list` of 2-`tuple`s, each consisting of comment and function name. Note `re.DOTALL` meaning that `.*?` might give multiline match and escaping of characters with special meaning, namely `*` as `\*`.

Answer (score 1):

```
  x = find_comment(x, "/*", "*/", 2)
  x = find_comment(x, "//", "\n", 0)
  def find_comment(n_array, start_string, end_string, add_index):
     comment_index = n_array.find(start_string)
     if comment_index != -1:
         comment_end_index = n_array.find(end_string, comment_index)
         print(comment_end_index)
         if len(n_array) > comment_end_index:
             print(n_array[comment_index:comment_end_index + add_index])
             n_array = n_array[0: comment_index:] + n_array[comment_end_index + add_index::]
             find_comment(n_array, start_string, end_string, add_index)
             return n_array
      return n_array
```

Comment: Add description of your answer